# Using number of leaves taken field i need to calculate number of remaining leaves,loss of pay and leave taken in total

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

```
USE [ctsdev]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Leavetbl](
    [Emp_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Month] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [Year] [varchar](4) NULL,
    [Rec_Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [CompanyName] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [Task] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [NoOfDaysLeavTakn] [int] NOT NULL,
    [NoOfAvailblLeav] [int] NULL,
    [LossofPay] [int] NULL,
    [LeaveTakndates] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [TtlLeavTakn] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_Leavetbl] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Emp_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

This is my table design.When the employee fills the number of leaves taken field ,with that value i need to find the remaining available leaves,like in an year only 12 leaves is permitted,and the total leaves he taken till to this month also have to display.
Is it possible through a procedure or any function ,could you please suggest some idea regarding this

Comment: Can you show output?

Comment: What does a row in this table correspond to? What is the relationship between `NoOfDaysLeavTakn`, `NoOfAvailblLeav`, `LeaveTakndates` and `TtlLeavTakn`? `LeaveTakndates` smells like a list of dates in some more or less descriptive prose, i.e. a terrible idea.

Comment: yup.... NoOfDaysLeavTakn  is the textbox field with numeric value not a date .suppose    NoOfDaysLeavTakn: 3(i entered)    ,then    the 'NoOfAvailblLeav'  field should  filled with (12-3) here 12 is the total paid leave in an year. Again LeaveTakndates  is the dates which user took leave    and finall TtlLeavTakn is the total number of leaves he took until this month

Comment: @Hebele have you got any idea about this?

Comment: I'll bow out. There seem to be too many questions/issues here.

Comment: @hari Edit question please

Comment: Yea.. @HABO actually i got some logic but dont know how to implement that ,it is a simple equation which solve my issue..could you please help me out with that

Comment: This is the logic which i got..could you please help me to implement this with procedure
NoOfDaysLeavTakn    : z
NoOfAvailblLeav    :?   
Four variables are there x,y,z and a----
a=1 always------
y=joining month number,if i joined in feb it will be 2------
z=number of days leave taken------
x=[12-(y-a)]------
?=[x-z]